# Pending Unconfirmed Transaction for 5 days

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I have been waiting on this transaction to confirm since July 16th when I made it. I have no idea as to why this transaction is not being fulfilled. Here is the blockchain of the transaction.
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3FpnL3kikVBm1mifSqebiuxHL6rcwe7K8B
Please someone help ; I just want to get the coins returned to my Coinbase Wallet (the origin address).

Comment: You linked to an address, with in addition no transaction related to it.

Answer (score 1):

Unconfirmed bitcoin transactions are also known as the transactions in the mempool.

The Bitcoin Mempool (memory pool) is a collection of all transaction data in a block that have been verified by Bitcoin nodes, but are not yet confirmed.

Once a transaction is included in a block, it has one confirmation. As soon as another block is mined on the same blockchain, the transaction has two confirmations, and so on. Six or more confirmations is considered sufficient proof that a transaction cannot be reversed.

In your case you have probably sent a transaction with a low feerate; for this reason all other transactions that have paid a higher commission than yours will be confirmed faster, while you will have to wait for your turn.

You just have to wait until mempool is clean. Transactions are cheaper and faster when the mempool is empty.
You can check websites like [Johoe's Bitcoin Mempool Statistics](https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#0,24h) or [mempool.space](https://mempool.space/) to see mempool statistics in real time.

Ps: what you sent us is not a transaction, but an address.
To be able to help you we would need the transaction, to understand if it is possible to carry out some actions aimed at speeding up the confirmation by the miners (eg RBF - Replace by Fee) instead of just waiting it to be confirmed.

Comment: On my coinbase account, the only thing that shows is a pending transaction to that address. There is no transaction ID/hash. It just shows the address the BTC were intended to be sent to, zero confirmations, and a fee of 0.00002088 BTC.

Comment: ^Continuing from that comment, I bought 300$ worth of BTC from Coinbase at 11:48 am on July 16th. Then in the same minute (11:48am), I sent the BTC to that address. Any ideas on what to do ?

Comment: Please, check in your email that you have not received a confirmation email from Coinbase.

Usually Coinbase, before sending the transaction, asks you to confirm it through a link in the email.
Have you already confirmed it?

Comment: @RiccardoMasutti: This last thing sounds like the most likely explanation given that there was not a transaction on the blockchain yet.